# ng-bind-html returning separate elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return, return-value

How can I return these vars from my controller to use in my view as separate elements?

My controller.

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.sharelinks =function () {


    var myVar = x; //EDIT**

    var emailLink = '<a>Some info here (i use x)</a>'; //EDIT**

    var twitterLink = '<a>Some info here(i also use x)</a>'; //EDIT**

    var newMarkup = [emailLink,twitterLink];

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(newMarkup);
  };
})
```

View.

```
<div ng-bind-html="sharelinks[0]"></div>    
<div ng-bind-html="sharelinks[1]"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sharelinks` is a function, but used as an array. Try doing this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="sharelinks()[0]"></div>    
<div ng-bind-html="sharelinks()[1]"></div>
```

Although I would just change it to something like:

```
var emailLink = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a>Some info here</a>');
var twitterLink = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a>Some info here</a>');

$scope.sharelinks = [emailLink,twitterLink];
```

And leave the view as it is.

**UPDATE:** I've read your question once again. If you want to not use any arrays but just links straight, just put them on scope, like this:

```
$scope.emailLink = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a>Some info here</a>');
$scope.twitterLink = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a>Some info here</a>');
```

And on the view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="emailLink"></div>    
<div ng-bind-html="twitterLink"></div>
```

Comment: the div's you have suggested to change are in the view what do you mean by leave the view as it is? I have tried this with little success.